# A thane is a person granted the honorary title of?

Tags: single-word-requests, titles, research

[> A knight is a person granted an honorary title of knighthood by a monarch or other political leader for service to the monarch or country, especially in a military capacity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight)

As a knight is one who is granted knighthood (or the title of knighthood), a thane is someone who is granted the title of what?

Also-
as one can be knighted, or granted said title of knighthood, can one be "thaned"? Is there a verb form of giving this honorary distinction as well?

Comment: [thanehood:](http://anglish.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Old_English_Words_in_the_OED/TH) "The condition or rank of a thane". Here's that exact definition in [the full OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200136), but you won't be able to follow that link unless you have a subscription. But it's regularly-formed, so I knew what to look up without being consciously aware of seeing the word before. Which to my mind makes it General Reference at the ELU level. Using ***to thane*** as a verb would be comprehensible in any credible context, but you'd hardly expect a dictionary to back that one up.

Comment: If the English Stack Exchange is the not the place to be asking this question, I truly endeavor to find the answer, so please share with me where my question would be preferably asked.

Comment: OED also has ***thaneship***. But *please don't ask exactly what makes that different to **thanehood*** (I've no idea if a distinction could meaningfully be made). There's also ***thanedom***, which applies more to the territory rather than the office (but extrapolating from words like ***martydom***, I wouldn't see anything wrong with using that as an abstract noun for "the condition of being a thane"). But nobody talks about [thane-lands](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200137) today except in historical cintexts (that OED definition specifically says that "thane-land" is ***Hist.***).

Comment: In which country is "thane" a title today? Is there a history site more applicable?

Comment: I suggest asking on the google site.

Comment: It's easier to work with derivatives that still have some currency. When I look at [*granted the **earldom***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22granted+the+earldom%22) (over 9000 hits in Google Books) compared to [*granted the **earlship***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22granted+the+earlship%22) (just **2** hits), it's not obvious to me the "office/territory" distinction is applied in practice.

Comment: I suggest looking up thane, definition on google.  Among many other sources, you will find a definition at [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/thane).  If you still have a question, then ask again, either here or on SE's History site: https://history.stackexchange.com/, depending on the nature of your question.  But, please, do some research first!

Answer (score 1):

In comments FumbleFingers wrote:

> [thanehood:](http://anglish.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Old_English_Words_in_the_OED/TH) "The condition or rank of a thane". Here's that exact definition in [the full OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200136), but you won't be able to follow that link unless you have a subscription. But it's regularly-formed, so I knew what to look up without being consciously aware of seeing the word before. Which to my mind makes it General Reference at the ELU level. Using ***to thane*** as a verb would be comprehensible in any credible context, but you'd hardly expect a dictionary to back that one up.
>
> OED also has ***thaneship***. But *please don't ask exactly what makes that different to **thanehood*** (I've no idea if a distinction could meaningfully be made). There's also ***thanedom***, which applies more to the territory rather than the office (but extrapolating from words like ***martydom***, I wouldn't see anything wrong with using that as an abstract noun for "the condition of being a thane"). But nobody talks about [thane-lands](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200137) today except in historical cintexts (that OED definition specifically says that "thane-land" is ***Hist.***).

Furthermore, according to [Wikipedia, thegn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thegn)

> After the Norman conquest of England in 1066, William the Conqueror
> replaced the Anglo-Saxon aristocracy with Normans and the new Norman
> ruling class replaced the Anglo-Saxon terminology with Norman. In this
> process, king's thegns became barons, and thegns appear to have been
> merged in the class of knights.